# Does the McBits cryptosystem work without permutation matrix?

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, niederreiter

I'm studying post quantum cryptography and recently found [McBits](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/610.pdf) (PDF) that is a version of the [Niederreiter cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niederreiter_cryptosystem).

I think I understand most of how the system works, but got a bit confused when I looked at the generation of the keys. In the Niederreiter scheme there is a non singular binary matrix S and a permutation matrix P which I cannot seem to find in McBits.

Do they not use these matrices or have I missed something? 
If not, does it work without them?